# Attempted to access a session while the WebSphere Application Server was stopping

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

I'm working on Websphere v8.0.0.9 and started get the following error "java.lang.RuntimeException: SESN0007E: Attempted to access a session while the WebSphere Application Server was stopping"  .

I have a servlet that extends HttpServlet.  Basically I am calling my servlet many times with parameters like;

http://localhost:10039/testServlet?
name = "name"&
surname = "surname"&
.
.
.

I found a support page of IBM's ; http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI22912 .

But is there any reason why I suddenly started to get this error ? 
And any way of bypassing it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are suddenly seeing this message but the APAR is fixed in V8.0.0.10. Since you are running on V8.0.0.9 you should upgrade to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: But I'm not supposed to upgrade my server  version to 8.0.0.10 because of the reason that it must be consistent with the servers available in other environments.  Thanks though.